Estimating various outputs using PCA from various features
I have a situation where I am trying to come up with a function to predict different max altitude (in meters) of 5 seconds of various balls thrown by various players with different features such as weight, height (inches), age, years of playing sports. Sample data below:




Weight
Height
Age
Years in sports
Basketball
Football
Shotput ball
Soccer ball
PC1




Player 1
200
72
22
10
4
5
1
3
-0.630645


Player 2
180
66
22
10
7
3
2
6
3.649772


Player 3
250
68
22
10
3
6
1
5
-1.274679


Player 4
165
64
22
10
5
8
2
4
-1.900314


Player 5
205
70
22
10
6
5
1
2
0.155865



I'm planning on using PCA to get the eigenvectors for the various ball height (PC1 column included above) and let's say the first principal component explains 95% of variance. We know that the features such as weight, height, age, and years in sports are predictive factors of the various ball heights. How would one come up with a function to predict the various ball heights using the 4 features? I was thinking of attacking this problem from the view point of PC1 where maybe a multiple regression of the 4 features against the PC1 value could work where the goal is to estimate the PC1 value then afterwards using the eigenvectors to project and get the various ball height. What would be the best approach for a problem like this?

You may be interested in Partial Least Squares https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression

Hey John, thanks for your suggestion. PLS is a "Similar" solution to PCA, although definitely different in the way I thought to address the above problem by reducing the space of 4 output Y variables to just try to estimate it's PC1 then use loadings to project onto the 4 Y variable outputs. Anyways, I will give both a try and see which is a better fit.
